# "/#action" Route in Routes.rb in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes, fragment-identifier

How can I create a route of this format (in Ruby on Rails routes.rb file):

```
/#action/id
```

Specifically with the "#" character inserted before the action controller...for example, see http://lala.com/#album/some-album-id

thanks!

Comment: Just curious, what do you hope to achieve with changing the url? I cannot think of a reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual URL you are visiting there is `http://lala.com/`. The server does not see the `#album/some-album-id` piece, the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). That is seen solely by the browser.

There is a growing trend of building MVC apps with the views and controllers in the client/browser, rather than on the server. The application is implemented with JavaScript in the client, instead of with Ruby on the server. The server essentially becomes the API or the data-access layer, rather than being the piece that renders HTML.