# Single-Page application with Rails - URL Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-helper

I am working on an application built with rails where I need to be able to generate urls with a "#" character at the beginning, like so:

```
user_path outputs "#/user/1"
dashboard_url outputs "http://mydomain.com/#/dashboard"
```

..and so on...

Any ideas what might be the best way to override the URL helper?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275214/get-request-part-after-hash-sign

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612118/action-route-in-routes-rb-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1):

> I need to be able to generate urls with a "#" character at the beginning

Why? The server will never see anything after the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Such URLs won't be seen by Rails, and controllers won't be able to respond to them.

If you need to create a URL which ends with a fragment identifier, use [`:anchor`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

Comment: The server won't, but client-side javascript will.

http://orderedlist.com/blog/articles/building-evented-single-page-applications/